# should i install LVM in ubuntu server?

Tags: linux

should i install LVM in ubuntu server?

i have only one primary partition.

what happens if i dont install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LVM helps you organize and reallocate disk space better. It isn't required in most cases, but it causes only very little slowdown (2% maximum, if that) for a lot of benefit if your disk/volume configuration changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Whenever I've built a server without it, I always end up regretting it.  I tend to only create logical partitions big enough for the base install + 100%.  On a typical 160G drive, that leaves at least 140G unallocated and available for all sorts of shenanigans.

If you grow to love LVM, you'll also want to become familiar with XFS, as it allows you to grow a partition while it's mounted.

Comment: So does ext2/3/4, with a recent enough kernel.